# Predictive Modeling with Sklearn based on one variable

Tags: python, scikit-learn, prediction

Is there a way to take past 10 years of data (0,1) for 100 people for one behavior and predict year 11, the likelihood of it happening again. How to train and test this?

Seems like sklearn uses a bunch of features but trying to use only one such as if a product was bought, will it be bought the next year.

Comment: what have you tried so far ?
the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)